# HMVC MX_Controller not loading CI' _output function

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, hmvc

Normally, extending `CI_Controller` lets you use the function `_output` for rendering html outputs.

I'm using HMVC. `MX_Controller` doesn't load `_output` function.

I've tested it and run a couple of times.

Questions:

1 - Does `MX_Controller` inherits `CI_Controller`?

2 - How can I implement `_output`?

Comment: Yes `MX_Controller` inherits `CI_Controller`. Which `_output` are you talking about! I dont see it documented anywhere!!

Comment: @Broncha - take a look [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html)  at **processing output section**

Comment: @zeekerg, you need to show your code. and there are many consequences to use `_output` . not much to tell with no code preview

Comment: I use _output to set my layouts and settings on pages, thus _output function is being called first before loading the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc does indeed break the _output() functionality. I can't figure out how to submit the bug on bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

My workaround involved overriding the `Output` class & adding a hook to fire a custom output method. Here's what I did.

Overwrite the main `Output` class:

```
class MY_Output extends CI_Output
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // Overwrite the output
    public function my_output()
    {
        $content = $this->get_output();

        // do stuff to $content here

        $this->set_output($content);
        $this->_display();
    }
}
```

Then enable hooks in your config.

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

Then add this to your hooks config.

```
$hook['display_override'][] = array(
    'class' => '',
    'function' => 'custom_output',
    'filename' => 'custom_output.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
    );
```

Finally add the "custom_output.php" file to your hooks directory and add this.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
 * Customize the output
 */
function custom_output()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->output->my_output();
}
```

If you don't need to access any class variables, you can just edit the output right in the `custom_output()` function and not worry about overriding the `Output` class.

Very hacky, but it works. :)